# xCode 5.1 CopyPNGFile Error

Tags: ios, xcode5, xcode5.1

Since I installed XCode 5.1 today I get a CopyPNGFile Error for every image that is located in a folder where I did not create a folder reference.

So when I add a folder with images and create a folder reference for it and dont select the option "Create groups for any added folders" when importing then I dont get an error. And when I dont create a reference I get an error.

I used Xcode 5.1 until Beta 5 and never encountered problems before in the beta period.

In the build phases everything looks alright. No red marks.

Does anybody else have this problem too and maybe know why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I figured out that I only had to restart the mac. Seems like some kind of permission problem. After several hours of trying I feel like crying.